# CSS to slide and squish text up?

Tags: css-animations

I'm wondering if CSS alone can perform the following effect or if I need javascript?  Here's a video demo of what I mean

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HhJgoT7C8XI

Notice how the text slides up and has as "squish effect"?  The line items at the top change from a big line-height to a small line-height faster than the lines at the bottom.  Can this effect be achieved by CSS alone?  Or do I need javascript or a javascript plugin?

I tried to view the source code for the demo in the video, but I couldn't identify what's causing this effect.

Anyone have ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did achieve the squishing effect via CSS only by setting a different `transition-delay:` for each element.